# Is it okay to use 'to name a few' with a colon

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, colons

Is the following sentence correct?

> The list had a variety of foodstuffs: oranges, apples, bananas and sardines to name a few.

Is it okay to use the phrase 'to name a few' with a colon, and also do I need to put a comma before 'to name a few'?

Comment: It's fine, just make sure to add a comma after the list and before "to name a few."

Comment: "Etc." is [synonymous](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/to_name_a_few.html) with "to name a few". I don't see why not.

Comment: I think the phrase you want is "to name **but** a few."

Comment: @Greybeard With or without "but" is fine: see [Farlex Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+name+a+few)

Answer (score 1):

One of the functions of the colon is to introduce a following list

> [Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823034011/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/colon)

Hence, your colon usage is correct. Your list is separated properly by commas with *and* as the last conjunction. But the list’s qualifying phrase *to name a few* needs to be separated from it by a comma. Otherwise we have the momentary image of talking sardines!